# non-significant interaction, (p=.438) becomes significant?

Tags: interaction

```
Outcome: BDI  


Model Summary   
          R        R-sq         MSE           F         df1         df2           p   
      .7248      .5254    38.6534    42.6772     3.0000   114.0000      .0000   

Model   
              coeff         se          t          p       LLCI       ULCI   
constant    16.7490      .6208    26.9791      .0000    15.5192    17.9789   
Ruminate      .4836      .1528     3.1643      .0020      .1808      .7863   
Victim        .4003      .0514     7.7828      .0000      .2984      .5022   
int_1         .0083      .0107      .7789    **.4377**     -.0128      .0294   

Product terms key:   

 int_1    Victim      X     Ruminate   

R-square increase due to interaction(s):   
         R2-chng          F        df1        df2          p   
int_1      .0025      .6067     1.0000   114.0000      .4377   

*************************************************************************   

Conditional effect of X on Y at values of the moderator(s):   
   Ruminate     Effect         se          t          p       LLCI       ULCI   
     3.7970      .3688      .0616     5.9881      **.0000**      .2468      .4908   
      .0000      .4003      .0514     7.7828      **.0000**      .2984      .5022   
     3.7970      .4319      .0692     6.2455      **.0000**      .2949      .5689
```

Why is the interaction non-significant (p=.438), but the conditional effect at 3 values of the moderator is significant, (p<.001)?

Thank-you!

Answer (score 1):

The `int_1` $p = .438$ means that the interaction is not significant. Below, you are looking at *conditional effects* of X (the IV) on Y (the IV) at three different levels of the moderators; it is *probing* the interaction effect. These, by default, are -1 SD, M, and +1 SD at the moderator. This is showing you that the effect is significant and in the same direction at all levels of the moderator—thus confirming that the interaction is not significant.